# Question about the usage of CRITICAL_SECTION

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Given the following code,

```
class MyCriticalSection : protected CRITICAL_SECTION
{
public:
    MyCriticalSection()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(this);
        EnterCriticalSection(this);
    }
    ~MyCriticalSection()
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(this);
        DeleteCriticalSection(this);
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : m_Int(0) {}

    int GetNum() 
    { 
        MyCriticalSection myCriticalSectionA;  // LockA

        return m_Int; 
    }

    int SetNum(int i)
    {
        MyCriticalSection myCriticalSectionB;  // LockB

        m_Int = i;
    }
protected:
    int m_Int;
};
```

I assume that the above design is correct, please correct me if you find some errors.
The usage of LockA has two capabilities: 1> it prevents the function GetNum from being call at the same time by more than one thread. 2> it prevents the functions GetNum and SetNum from accessing the m_Int at the same time.

Here is my question:
The variables myCriticalSectionA and myCriticalSectionB are two different instances of class MyCriticalSection. Why they can collaborate with each other so that the lock mechanism work as expect?

My guess is that somehow the CRITICAL_SECTION has some static flag so that different instances of it can communicate each other.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

==== Update ====

```
class MyCriticalSection : protected CRITICAL_SECTION
{
public:
    MyCriticalSection()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(this);

    }
    ~MyCriticalSection()
    {       
        DeleteCriticalSection(this);
    }
    void Lock()
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(this);
    }
    void UnLock()
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(this);
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : m_Int(0) {}

    int GetNum() 
    { 
        m_Lock.Lock();
        // do something here
        m_Lock.UnLock();
        return m_Int; 
    }

    int SetNum(int i)
    {
        m_Lock.Lock();      
        m_Int = i;
        m_Lock.UnLock();
    }
protected:
    int m_Int;
    MyCriticalSection m_Lock;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think that the two instances are actually "collaborating" (and that the code is correct)?

Comment: @aix, I think I incorrectly made assumption that this critical section is similar as what Java provides as a synchronized method. -- thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your update is no better.  If you want to do this in an RAII style then you need to work a bit harder.  The key is that you need to separate the critical section object which is statically allocated, and the lock which is local to all blocks that need protection.

The following is lifted from [Jonathan Dodds](http://jrdodds.blogs.com/blog/2004/08/raii_in_c.html) but it is a classic pattern.

```
class CriticalSection
{
public:
    CriticalSection()
        { ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_rep); }
    ~CriticalSection()
        { ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_rep); }

    void Enter()
        { ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_rep); }
    void Leave()
        { ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_rep); }

private:
    // copy ops are private to prevent copying
    CriticalSection(const CriticalSection&);
    CriticalSection& operator=(const CriticalSection&);

    CRITICAL_SECTION m_rep;
};
```

Whilst you could do this with inheritance of CRITICAL_SECTION, I feel encapsulation is more appropriate.

Next the lock is defined:

```
class CSLock
{
public:
    CSLock(CriticalSection& a_section)
        : m_section(a_section) { m_section.Enter(); }
    ~CSLock()
        { m_section.Leave(); }

private:
    // copy ops are private to prevent copying
    CSLock(const CSLock&);
    CSLock& operator=(const CSLock&);

    CriticalSection& m_section;
};
```

Finally, an example of usage:

```
class Example
{
public:
    bool Process( … );

    …

private:
    CriticalSection m_criticalsection;

    …
};

bool Example::Process( … )
{
    CSLock lock(m_critsection);

    // do some stuff
    …
}
```

The point is that there is a single instance of the critical section, shared across all threads. This is what makes a critical section work.

In counterpoint, there may be many instances of `CSLock`, all taken on the same critical section, in simultaneous existence.  This allows the `Process()` method to be called by many threads, but have its code is serialized over the lifetime of the `CSLock` instance taken on the single shared critical section.

Comment: Thanks. Glad you are sorted out now. Of course, I copied the code! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are completely wrong. Two `CRITICAL_SECTION`s are totally unrelated- how else would programs create more than one lock? Look at the `boost::thread` library for how to design the interface.

Comment: Based on my design, the LockA can only prevent the function GetNum from being call at the same time by more than one thread. Is this correct? -- thx

Comment: @q0987: No. You create a new lock every time you enter the function, so every thread will be making a new lock and locking it, not locking or trying to lock the same lock.

Comment: may you take a further look at my update? Is the update correct or not? -- thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the code you proposed you are blocking concurrent read and concurrent writes but not interlocking the two operation. To achieve what you want you shoud use a single CriticalSession object.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has its own stack, and your lock variable is located on stack, which means the lock can't protect between threads.

Code snippit;

```
class CSLock
{
public:
       CSLock( CriticalSection& cs )
       { 
            EnterCriticalSection( cs );
       }
       ~CSLock()
       {
            LeaveCriticalSection( cs );
       }
 };

 class Client
 {
 public:
       Client()
       {}
       void Fun()
       {
           CSLock( m_cs );
       }
 private:
       CriticalSection m_cs;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you are pretty far off the base here.

<del>First, even though I don't have any Windows installs to verify this, I'm pretty sure you cannot inherit from `CRITICAL_SECTION` like this.</del>

Then, you are **not** locking anything anywhere with this setup, just slowing things down. Every entry into `Get` or `Set` creates and initializes *new* critical section, which is specific to that thread and that particular call. You need to have CS *shared* between calls - make them class members at least.